# import C array into Eigen Transform Matrix?

Tags: c++, eigen

How can I assign a C array into Eigen::Transform? For some reason Eigen::Map does not accept Eigen::Transform as its template parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map a matrix and assign it to the transform object, e.g.:

```
float* data = ...;
Affine3f transform(Matrix4f::Map(data));
// or later:
transform = Matrix4f::Map(data);
```